# How to implement move up a VIew to top page transparent side while scrolling in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, scroll

I want to implement a scroll view that when scrolling it up, the content goes to a dark side of the page (like the image). What's the name of this type of scrolling and how can I implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `CollapsingToolbar`.

You can find ready library to use. like **[this](https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-collapsing-toolbar)** & **[this](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-collapsible-toolbar)**.